# Serial closers in area 51

Tags: discussion, abuse

I've noticed that closed proposals in Area 51 are closed by a small set of people who repeatedly appear in the closed by lists.  Has anyone looked into this?

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28158/stocks-discussion

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29624/learn-whatever

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29580/spirituality-and-scientology

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29528/french-language-usage

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29397/pick-up-artist

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29379/android

Some of them appear in only most of the lists, but a couple of those names appear in each and every closed proposal.  Seems questionable.

That's just the first 6 (minus my own, which also has many of the same people) closed proposals.

Comment: Hmm, maybe that's because those are the only 7 people who hang out on Area51 enough to have rep to close? `:P`

Comment: Wow, seems like the ones that were closed should have been and the one dup was a dup.  This does not see like abuse at all.

Comment: @John - possibly.  Maybe the rep barrier should be lowered a touch over there.  It's kind of a funky place.  Not many ways to actually MAKE rep unless you just run around trolling everything.

Comment: @Crazy: I think most everyone knows that something is wrong with Area51, just everyone has different ideas on how to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the new [Area 51 Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), users have their first opportunity to organize and start cleaning up Area 51. There's certainly no shortage of proposals that *need* to be closed and combined.

But the role of the discussion forums (or even Area 51, in general) is *not* to have a handful of Meta Area 51 users police the place and pass judgment on every proposal. Discussions are meant for stake holders to have a forum to communicate important issues about their proposals.

When I was sole proprietor of Area 51, my philosophy was to NOT close down people's (poor) ideas. If there's no "market" for a Q&A idea, nobody would support it. I preferred to let that *lack* of support be the primary means of culling unpopular ideas.

**Having said that,** I'm hesitant to say what they are doing is wrong or unwelcomed. Most of the proposals closed probably *should* have been closed. It's mostly low-hanging fruit activities and, to date, the ends have justified the means.

Truth be told, **I'd rather see people spending more of their time fixing up [the proposals on the *commitment end* of the process](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress).** That's where it counts. The rest is largely inconsequential.

There is still a strong editorial layer in Area 51. We're still getting used to the new discussion process. If I see the process being abused and legitimate proposals closed for the wrong reasons, I have no qualms about stepping in an saying, "If you don't like it, don't support it."

Comment: Yeah, I've seen you come in and say maybe it's time to close this.  I thought it was well reasoned.  It also happens to be in my list.  Just seemed weird to see the same people over and over again.

Comment: What we need is more participation in Area 51 so the democracy is *more* effective. The process is new. It will happen in time.